# is this code using 960 grid is correct?

Tags: 960.gs

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="container_16">
<div id="footer_title" class="grid_16"> history &nbsp; <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.show('footer_content')"><img src="{$AltImagesDir}/collapse_down.gif" height="7" width="6" border="0" /> expand</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.hide('footer_content')"><img src="{$AltImagesDir}/collapse_up.gif" height="7" width="6" border="0" /> collapse</a> </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer_content" class="grid_16">
  <div class="grid_4 alpha" id="f_left_content">Left Content Here</div>
  <div class="grid_3">1st Column Content Here</div>
  <div class="grid_3">2nd Column Content Here</div>
  <div class="grid_3">3rd Column Content Here</div>
  <div class="grid_3 omega">4th Column Content Here</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer_bottom" class="grid_16"><a href="#">About Us</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#">Policies</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#">Help</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#">Contact Us</a> </div>
```

The last grid_3 omega class pushes down and doesn't lay on the level of first 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the margins between the colunms. Delete this div (id="footer_content"). you do not need it or delete the class definition of this div...

Or make a new div that wrap the inner divs of div id="footer_content".

But you can always use the Generator on the 960.gs site

BTW: Do you have borders in your css definitions? You must remove all borders, because float is precise and will break if you make the elements any larger than the framework defined.

Comment: Hi Mika I cannot delete the id="footer_content because the middle row toggle on and off the only property of footer_content is display:block and none.

Comment: Then delete the class definition or make a inner div wrapper to clear the margin of the div with grid_16. The margin of grid_16 and the margins of the inner divs are the problem...